# Meaning of int... or N... in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a function from a library whose signature says:-

`public void setColumnNames(N... columnNames);`

**1.) What is the meaning of 'N...' ?**

Also I have a list like this:-
`List<HColumn<String,String>>`

I want to extract the 1st String of each element `HColumn` of this list and pass all these Strings as a single argument in above function. I am doing this job to compute the things that need to be displayed on a page of a website. Thus *I need a superfast method* to do so.

**2.) How do I go for it ??**

Comment: 1) Varargs http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: 2) Build an array of type N[] with the same length as the list, transfer the strings from the list to the array (converting them from String to N, however that's done), and pass the array as the argument to the function.

Comment: @Vance you should consider putting those in an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking glowcoder's suggestion, here's the other part:

2) Build an array of type N[] with the same length as the list, transfer the strings from the list to the array (converting them from String to N, however that's done), and pass the array as the argument to the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void setColumnNames(N... columnNames)
```

means that `setColumnNames` takes any number of arguments of type `N`.

This feature is called [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).